# html5 loop issue

Tags: html, video

I cannot figure out how to make my html5 video loop correctly when I set a start and end time.
I am trying like this

src="redsmoke.mp4#t=13,15" autoplay loop

It starts fine at the specified time (13) and stops on the specified time(15) but will not loop

Answer (score 0):

The loop attribute isn't widely supported by browsers yet. Which one were you trying it on?

Comment: just chrome, the loop works fine until I try to set the start/end time

Comment: I suspect that the loop doesn't work with the start end time configuration then. You'll probably have to write your own functionality in JavaScript.